# Graph portion of Excel table in Word with a macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

So for background, I get a excel workbook from another department that is full of a information for a specific account that I then take and use certain parts to create graphs in word. Is there a way I could create a macro what would grab the data from Ex. C22:H34, put it into a template word document and possibly auto populate the graphs as well? I want to make it a process that I can hand off to other people to do, so the simpler it is to execute, the better.

Here is what I have

```
Sub AutoNew()
'
' AutoNew Macro
'
'
Dim xlapp As Object
Dim xlbook As Object
Dim xlsheet As Object
Dim bstartApp As Boolean
Dim i As Long
On Error Resume Next
Set xlapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err Then
    bstartApp = True
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Set xlbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\MattsonC\Documents\work\Copy of 
3202_2018_Renewal Rate Workbook v2 EDIT.xlsx")
Set xlsheet = xlbook.Sheets(1)
With xlsheet.Range("A1")
    For i = 1 To .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
        ActiveDocument.Variables(.Offset(i, 0)).Value = .Offset(i, 2)
    Next i
End With
xlbook.Close
If bstartApp = True Then
    xlapp.Quit
End If
Set xlapp = Nothing
Set xlbook = Nothing
Set xlsheet = Nothing
ActiveDocument.Range.Fields.Update
End Sub
```

I have variables done like {DOCVARIABLE LLY} in all the places I want data to go in the template, and renamed the cells in excel with the same variable name.

I can't get any output to happen in my Word document, any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes it can be done, but can you please show us what you've tried on your own first?

Comment: And what error are you getting on that line?

Comment: Have you tried using the `Sheets` collection, i.e. `Set xlsheet = xlbook.Sheets(1)`?

Comment: `giving me issues` does not provide any useful information

Comment: it is giving a run-time error 438

Comment: Sheets(1) not Sheet(1) as per YowE3K's suggestion?

Comment: I tried that, and it has eliminated the error, but I am still not able to get the data to show up in the word document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go back to the beginning

insert a document variable in a new word document using following sequence (word 2016)

```
insert tab … text … quick parts … field … categories: document automation … field names: docVariable … put in variable name xxxx
```

then run this code

```
Sub aaa()

    'ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = Not ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes  ' toggle field code view
    Stop
    ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
    Stop
    ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False

    ActiveDocument.Variables("xxxx").Value = "abc123"
    ActiveDocument.Range.Fields.Update

    Stop

    ActiveDocument.Variables("xxxx") = "xyz987"
    ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

End Sub
```

if that works, then use the code with the document that you are having trouble with and figure out if your field names are what you think they are